# implementing Kapt is causing build errors in autogenerated files of retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, build.gradle, android-room

I been working in a Android Project (Kotlin) where i been using retrofit with no problem. Now i need to implement a database and the natural option to use Room for that

So i add the dependencies in build.gradle as always

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
```

i hit the "sync" button and the project is alright, but when i try to actually build the project it fails with this error

```
    Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
    > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

and this error associated with some auto generated file of retrofit

```
/home/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/myproject/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/tk/myuser/myproject/Retrofit/RetrofitRetriever.java:90: error: <identifier> expected
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super tk.myuser.myproject.Retrofit.DataClasses.import> p1) {
```

This error only appears when i try to build the project with the **Kapt** dependency enable otherwise it works perfectly fine

I already tried cleaning the project, deleting Android Studio cache, deleting temp files and analyzing the code but nothing seems to help

Comment: Ok my problem was related to the way i declare the dataclasses for my project. 

1. Some of the dataclasses were in lowercase
2. Some of their names were reserved 

After changing the names all the problems were gone :)